# install syslog-ng on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, syslog-ng

I've just finished installing a fresh installation of syslog-ng on CentOS 7, but syslog-ng.service failed to start.
It says:

> Failed to issue method call: Unit syslog.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're using CentOS 7. Since CentOS 6, `rsyslog` has since replaced the regular `syslog` packages. `rsyslog` is a drop-in replacement and works the same. You more than likely already have it.

```
# systemctl status rsyslog.service
```

Comment: sorry, I'm not using rsyslog. Iwant o use syslog-ng for collect logs.

Answer (score 0):

It may (no promises) have to do with the way you installed syslog-ng.  If you use EPEL, you can simply run `yum install syslog-ng` then start.  I've used this on all my servers without incident.

If not that, then I would suggest checking the journal (use `journalctl`) to see why the service failed to start.  By the message above the syslog.service is missing.  I've always used syslog.socket if anything, but was anything done to the server to affect that or was something changed in syslog-ng.conf to call that?